# List not being returned for any value greater than 2

Tags: python

I have written a short piece of code that is a component of a larger game. It is a position/word type game, where a person is prompted to guess a section of a mystery word, with a prompted position and length of said guess. The code is as follows for the list of tuples that are (position,length) for a given guess:

```
def trial(word_length):
    direction = True
    position = 0
    guess_length = 2
    steps = []
    while word_length != guess_length:
        while direction == True:
            steps.append((position,guess_length))
            if position != 0:
                position -= 1
            else:
                guess_length += 1
                direction = False               
        while direction == False:
            steps.append((position,guess_length))
            if (position + guess_length) < word_length:
                position += 1
            else:
                position -= 1
                guess_length += 1
                direction = True
    steps.append((0,word_length))
    return steps
```

This code generates the list for word_length 2, but does not for any greater. I need it, to be able to work up to 10 letter words. Any reason it is choosing to not return the list?

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Any reason it is choosing to not return the list?

Your code is going into an **endless loop**, because `position` becomes negative.

Change to the following.

```
while word_length != guess_length and position >= 0:
```